# How to solve this error - ORA-22818: subquery expressions not allowed?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT first_name, (select min(salary) from hr.employees where department_id = 103), (select max(salary) from hr.employees where department_id = 103)
from hr.employees where hr.employees.department_id = 103;
```

But it shows an error:

subquery expressions not allowed here

Do you know how to solve the error?

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN's instead.

Comment: @Mary Your query is valid Oracle syntax and runs fine on my database. I assume you are getting the error because you are using the query in some unusual context, like as part of a materialized view. Can you edit your question and add some details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` a *derived table* (aka inline view) that returns each department's min and max salary:

```
SELECT e.first_name,
       e2.min_sal,
       e2.max_sal
from hr.employees e
left join (select department_id, min(salary) min_sal, max(salary) max_sal
           from hr.employees
           group by department_id) e2
  on e.department_id = e2.department_id
where e.department_id = 103;
```

Comment: @Mary, sorry, but I don't know Oracle's date/time functionality. (I've never used Oracle.)

Comment: Other employees with the same department_id 103? You can let the subquery return count(*).

Comment: To get better help, ask another question.

Comment: count(*) alone in the the subquery. Case in the main select.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is kinda old but I've found neat "hack" for this oracle limitation.
If you create a normal view and then create a materialized view using that view then oracle will allow it.

Example1 (this will throw error):

```sql
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW VW_TEST2;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW VW_TEST2 AS
SELECT ROWNUM AS rowNumber, vw.* from (
SELECT 1 as ID, 'Test1' as Txt from dual
union all
select (select 2 from dual) as ID, 'Test2' as Txt from dual) vw;
```

Example2 (this will not throw error)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_TEST1 AS
SELECT ROWNUM AS rowNumber, vw.* from (
SELECT 1 as ID, 'Test1' as Txt from dual
union all
select (select 2 from dual) as ID, 'Test2' as Txt from dual) vw;

DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW VW_TEST2;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW VW_TEST2 AS
SELECT * FROM VW_TEST1;
```